# How to pass id from create action to another action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok I have two methods

```
def join_group
  @user = User.find(current_user[:id])
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.groups << @group
      format.html {redirect_to @group}
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :index}
    end
  end
end

def create
  @group = Group.new(group_params)
  @group.created_by = current_user.id
  respond_to do |format|
    if @group.save
      format.html { redirect_to @group }
      format.js
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @group }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @group.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And I want to make that after `create` action `join_group` is called. I was trying `after_action :join_group, only: [:create]` but i don't know how to pass `id` into `join_group` and I ended up with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Group with 'id'=):`

Comment: One thing(not the best way) you can do is take last record in `Group` table and assign it to `@group` in `join_group` method. Because, it goes to that action after creating a group. But the best way is @Jared answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a completely separate action to add the user after you create it you could just set it up in the create method.

```
def create
  #adds user to the group and builds it like you have it.
  @group = current_user.groups.build(group_params.merge(created_by: current_user.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @group.save
      format.html { redirect_to @group }
      format.js
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @group }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @group.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

But if you do want it separate I would add it as a method on the group and just pass the User ID to it.